# Slideshow module

Tags: 7, javascript, views

I am looking for a slider module that can achieve sliding four video nodes at a time

[image]

Have already tried with Views slideshow (managed to do it but with only one video at a time not four as below), FlexSlider (requires image field, I do not have) and jCarousel (do not provide with a touch event). Any suggestions or tips are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it Views slideshow. In Views slideshow settings, use "View Action Advanced Options" and add 4 "Items per slide". see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This will do the job I think. Thank you very much ;) Cheers

Comment: Brilliant, done it with Views Slideshow and some template tweaking. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Could try with :

1. **Dynamic display block** : This slideshows are mainly used to showcase featured content at a prominent place on the frontpage in an attractive way. A featured content slideshow can contain e.g.: New articles, Most popular content, New products, Portfolios, Videos etc
   Refer from http://drupal.org/project/ddblock
2. **Feature content slider** : This is a module to feature latest nodes in a block that displays as a slideshow. This makes a featured slideshow out of node content displayed in the block. With this module, you can control options like fade, auto-rotate, speed etc. This module can be associated with multiple content types and be configured with multiple blocks
   Refer from http://drupal.org/project/content_slider

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows developers and themers to make use of the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.
>
> Features:
>
> - Built-in Views support.
> - AJAX-loading of additional items as needed.
> - Carousel pager/navigation to jump between multiple pages.
> - Circular wrapping of items.
> - API for direct usage of jCarousel without Views.